# Site contactform.php has incorrect file permissions - nginx error 405 (not allowed)

Tags: php, nginx, permissions

#### I have contacted digital ocean support team and they believe that my www/data files have incorrect file permissions

"This error indicates a permissions issue within your site. You will need to make sure that the web server user most likely www-data has access to the files and applications needed to send mail using the form. You should be able to track down the exact filenames of the attempted access in your site's access logs." - digital ocean support team

#### I checked the nginx acccess log

> 70.54.134.32 - - [14/Mar/2017:14:58:34 +0000] "POST /contact_me.php HTTP/1.1" 405 584 "https://cormaccrowley.com/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

#### I'm getting a 405 not allowed error - The contact_me.php file permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1218 Mar 14 00:05 contact_me.php
```

#### And here is my php script

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'c[MY-EMAIL-WAS-HERE]'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@cormaccrowley.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

[image: Here is an image of the chrome inspect network window]

Answer (score 1):

The files within your directory will need to be readable by the user nginx is running as. You will have to change the permissions with the [chown](https://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/chown.php) linux function : 
`chown www-data:www-data contact_me.php`

Comment: I just tried that and got `chown: invalid user: ‘nginx:nginx’`

Comment: Please try with www-data so

Comment: Use `www-data so` in the place of `nginx:nginx` ?

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the 405 error :(.  What is `www-data` ?  My /var/www directory has no `data` directory?

Comment: www-data is normaly the user which runs your PHP scripts. So it's must be able to read and execute the file. I think you have to find out which user is running for your webserver and chown for it

Comment: Ok, so now my contact_me.php has the following permissions `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1218 Mar 14 00:05 contact_me.php`.  I'm still receiving the 405 error though.

Comment: can you try to do `chmod 755 contact_me.php` ?

Comment: Ok tried that:  File permission now `-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 1218 Mar 14 00:05 contact_me.php` with contact_me.php in green.  Still getting 405 error and the form isn't submitting.  Relevant info: I'm running postfix on my server.  The php mail() command is works in terminal, but the script doesn't run on the page.  The `POST` seems to be triggering the 405 error in the php.

Comment: How would I go about figuring out which user is running for my webserver?  Thanks for the help by the way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Too many issues being discussed. If the chown solved the initial problem then set the answer as resolved and open a new one please. At this moment it is unclear what is going on.